# Cannot use .NET 6.0 Framework for ASP.NET with React.js and Redux in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have .NET 6.0 Runtime selected in individual components, what's weird is I don't have .NET 5.0 Runtime selected.

[No .NET 6 option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdCou.png)

[Have .NET 6 installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeNQh.png)

Answer (score 0):

VS2022 recommends you split front end and back end into different projects (and use `.esproj` especially),

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2022?view=vs-2022

Thus, that project template you selected shouldn't apply to .NET 6, or unnecessary problems are there.

Answer (score 0):

Official announcement is that .net 6 will no longer support react + redux template still they will encourage the use of the front end frameworks of your choice providing alternatives to add react + redux to your .net 6 backend project.

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/465